# deprecated OnActivityResult() in androidx

Tags: android, androidx, deprecated, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

`OnActivityResult()` is deprecated in androidx. I took reference from below links

- https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result
- https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity
- https://proandroiddev.com/is-onactivityresult-deprecated-in-activity-results-api-lets-deep-dive-into-it-302d5cf6edd

I implemented for signup thing in my project ..like .I created resultcontract by registering the activity
in place of `startActivityForResult`   i replaced by  `resultcontract.launch(intent)` and getting result in `resultcontract`   (followed above links). Now i have doubt in one function that is turn on gps.
for this we have used

```
val rae = e as ResolvableApiException
rae.startResolutionForResult(context, GPS_REQUEST)
```

earlier it was  `startActivityForResult` , now it is  `startResolutionForResult`
having confusion how to get result of gps request ( in code , we are getting result in
onActivityResult).how can i implement this using new way?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, how do we implement this now? Have you found the solution?

Comment: No , i am still searching for the solution. If you find any ,please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: startResolutionForResult() uses onActivityResult to notify it, and we can't replace it to provide an equal solution using the new way of Intents. So I'm keeping the same solution for now! I tried my best but can't find another way. Sorry

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem, using the recent API's to start something for result.

So, you can pretty much get the resolution from `ResolvableApiException`, which is a `PendingIntent`, and start it with `StartIntentSenderForResult` contract, like this

contract:

```
private val resolutionForResult = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()
) { activityResult ->

    // do whatever you want with activity result...

}
```

how to start:

```
.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
    if (exception is ResolvableApiException) {
        try {
            val intentSenderRequest = IntentSenderRequest
                    .Builder(exception.resolution).build()
            resolutionForResult.launch(intentSenderRequest)
        } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
            // Ignore the error.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay. , and if you consider my above code, then how to pass GPS Request?

Comment: you dont need GPS_REQUEST constant doing by this way, since resolutionForResult contract is created specific to get result of IntentSender. this callback give you a ActivityResult which have your data(Intent) and resultCode(Int). I'm just doing this on callback private val resolutionForResult =
        fragmentActivity.registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()) { activityResult ->
            if (activityResult.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    startRequestLocationUpdates()
            }
        }

Comment: Ok, i got it. Thank you so much Gustavo. one more doubt for  
        AutoResolveHelper.resolveTask(task, requireActivity(), SAVE_TO_WALLET)  this one we are sending for SAVE_TO_WALLET request and getting it result in onActivityResult ,  if (requestCode == SAVE_TO_WALLET) {
            sendActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }   how can we achieve this using new method?

Comment: Didn't work when I initialized callback inside a fragment method, so use class-level declaration only!