# onActivityResult is deprecated how do I send startResolutionForResult

Tags: android, gps, androidx, deprecated, onactivityresult

So I'm using a gps class to turn on the gps and here's a method that allow us to send to `onActivityResult`, but since is deprecated on AndroidX and *still available*, android team recommend us the next:

> *it is strongly recommended to use the Activity Result APIs introduced in AndroidX*

I have a the following code where I try to send to onActivityResult

```
val rae = e as ResolvableApiException
rae.startResolutionForResult(context,Constants.GPS_REQUEST)
```

How do I approach the same thing with the new API?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative

Comment: Since I'm accessing from a custom class that is "far from activity", I do need to make variable launcher public, access to activity variable, and then call it, is that a good practice?

Comment: no issues. you can do this

Comment: and so... how do I launch this?

Comment: I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65943223/4625681

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What I did in Kotlin was:

```
registerForActivityResult(StartIntentSenderForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Your logic
    }
}.launch(IntentSenderRequest.Builder(rae.resolution).build())
```

Original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65943223/4625681

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/ResolvableApiException#public-methods)
is described that is not deprecated

Comment: ResolvableApiException is not deprecated, onActivityResult is: [here says that is better to use a different approach developer](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

Answer (score 0):

Prepearing to listen for activity result:

```
private val onRequestSmartLockRetrieveCredentialsResultHandler = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult()
    ) { activityResult ->
        if (activityResult.resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            val credentials: Credential? = activityResult.data?.getParcelableExtra(Credential.EXTRA_KEY)
            //now we can pass credentials somewhere
            Toast.makeText(
                activity, "Retrieve: OK, Credentials: "
                    + credentials?.id + ", pass: " + credentials?.password, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Retrieve: FAIL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Starting activity for result:

```
val intentSenderRequest = IntentSenderRequest
                            .Builder(exception.resolution).build()
                        onRequestSmartLockRetrieveCredentialsResultHandler.launch(intentSenderRequest)
```